# Understanding the statement: An antenna with 20 degree beamwidth has 20 dB gain

Tags: antenna

It is known to us that as gain of an antenna increases, its beamwidth becomes narrower. Is there any formula to support the above statement?

Comment: Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern ? The idea is that if all the power that an antenna radiates is focused in a certain direction, that can be seen as "gain" as that antenna radiates more in that direction than an antenna that radiates equally in all directions. There are plenty of formulas that **describe** this behavior. Note that formulas **describe** behavior, a formula doesn't define it. A formula can be written that describes nonsense behavior. So don't go out hunting for formulas, instead figure out how things behave and look at the formulas describing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **An antenna with 20 degree beamwidth has 20 dB gain**

**That is an approximation**

In reality an antenna with 20 degree beamwidth has 21.2 dB gain. (If the beam is circular and not oval or otherwise distorted).

You only need to understand some simple geometry to see why this is true;

**Antenna gain is relative to that of a theoretical isotropic antenna**

*(..Ie. one which radiates evenly in all directions, in a sphere.)*

When we talk about an antenna having a gain of for instance 20dB, what we really mean is that; In the direction that the antenna is sensitive, the gain of the signal is 20dB compared to what it would be if the antenna was an isotropic antenna.

**It is very easy to see why this is the case..;**

An isotropic antenna radiates (and is sensitive) equally in all directions, so at a distance \$r\$ form the antenna, the power is spread over a sphere with that radius, the area of this sphere is \$4\pi r^2\$.

A directional antenna on the other hand only radiates (and is sensitive) within some vertical and horizontal angle, If we assume that the vertical and the horizontal angle is the same then the beam is circular (this is the simplest example).

Now imagine that you have a spherical surface, and from the centre you have a cone (beam) extending from the centre to the surface of the sphere.

Where the cone/beam intersects the spherical surface it encircles an area of the surface of the sphere, the area of this surface is; \$2\pi r^2(1-\cos (\theta/2))\$ where \$ \theta\$ is the angle of the beam.

To find the gain of the antenna we simply divide the are of the full sphere (isotropic antenna) by the area of the cone/beam on the sphere, like so;

\$ gain = \frac{4\pi r^2}{2 \pi r^2 (1-\cos(\theta /2))} = \frac{2}{1-\cos(\theta/2)} \$

To get the above in dB you need to do; \$ gain[dB] = 10\log(\frac{2}{1-\cos(\theta/2)})\$

Plug \$ \theta=20\$ into the above equation and you will get \$21.2dB\$

Comment: It is very clear to me now!

Comment: @Kaswechiha Awesome :), glad I could help..

Answer (score 3):

Study the following document: https://www.phys.hawaii.edu/~anita/new/papers/militaryHandbook/antennas.pdf
which discusses basic antenna theory. Equation 6 is what you want:

Antenna Gain (dB) = 10log(41253/VH) where V is the vertical beanwidth and H is the horizontal beamwidth (both in degrees). If you insert V and H as 20 degrees, then, indeed, the Antenna Gain is 20 dB.

Comment: It helped and clarified my query!

Answer (score 0):

An antenna appears to conjure power from thin-air but it cannot conjure power from nothing so, if it has high directionality (as opposed to it being isotropic) then it concentrates the emitted power out in one main direction. This means it has a tighter beam or, the beam-width is narrower.

It's a the same as an LED or lamp - if you focus the light beam it can be seen at a greater distance.

> *Is there any formula to support the above statement?*

No formula is required to support the statement because, by inspection, it has to be true.

Comment: I understood the LED analogy. What I'm not getting now is how they arrived at the gain value of 20 dBi? It could have been 17 dB also right?

Comment: Do you understand the term `dBi` as opposed to `dB` - you used one correctly and one incorrectly in your comment. Have you read [this](http://www.tscm.com/antennas.pdf) document?

Comment: I got clarified. It helped!